# moltype controlled vocabulary?

Tags: bioinformatics, ncbi

In submitting sequences using tbl2asn to NCBI/GenBank, the documentation states that there is a controlled vocabulary for the key "moltype", but no where on the Internet can I find a full list of that vocabulary.  "mRNA" and "genomic" are given as examples on several pages, and I can see from Sequin documentation what the GUI descriptors of all the vocabulary terms are (e.g., "genomic DNA"), but I can't find the terms themselves.  Any ideas where I can find this list?

Comment: Kind of a hassle, but could you download Sequin see what it outputs in the fasta for each molecule type?

Comment: I hadn't realized Sequin output fasta files.  I just checked, and it doesn't seem to include any of those descriptors in the FASTA file that will be exported when you use the Export command.

Comment: Sorry, I actually don’t know anything about it. Just a thought I had.

Comment: It was a good thought.  As you can see, I (perhaps inappropriately) edited my comment because I tested it out, and it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is [this "Controlled vocabulary for /mol_type qualifier" page](http://www.insdc.org/controlled-vocabulary-moltype-qualifier) created by the International Nucleotide Sequence Database Collaboration in 2013.  It says the allowed values are:

> "genomic DNA", "genomic RNA", "mRNA", "tRNA", "rRNA", "other RNA", "other DNA", "transcribed RNA", "viral cRNA", "unassigned DNA", "unassigned RNA"

I found this as the second result of a Google search on *moltype vocabulary*.

Comment: I found that too.  The issue with this is that in the examples provided by NCBI, "genomic" is one of the valid values "moltype".  "genomic" by itself does not appear on that controlled vocabulary list.

Comment: Of course, another possibility is that the other NCBI documentation if invalid, and that this is the controlled vocabulary they use as well.

Comment: I just heard back from NCBI.  Even though this controlled vocabulary conflicts with their own documentation (which I suspect is out-of-date), it is the vocabulary they now use.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an archived version of [Sequin for Database Submissions and Updates:
A Quick Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20151114054643/http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov:80/projects/Sequin/QuickGuide/sequin.htm), published by NCBI.

> - **moltype** should use one of the following values. Example: [moltype=genomic]
>
>   - genomic
>   - precursor RNA
>   - mRNA
>   - rRNA
>   - tRNA
>   - snRNA
>   - scRNA
>   - other-genetic
>   - cRNA
>   - snoRNA
>   - transcribed RNA

Comment: Great job!   That looks like it is what I need.  Odd that this isn't public.

Comment: The other possibility is that the OTHER documentation is out of date, and that the controlled vocabulary the mgkrebbs found is the one NCBI also uses.

Comment: @DavidMaddison Yes, it is odd. It may be worth contacting NCBI about it.

Comment: Yes, I sent NCBI a note asking about this earlier today.  I will report back!

Comment: See my new comment to mgkrebbs answer.